# "Deep" mathematical results used in computer-generated imagery

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, computational-mathematics, applications, image-processing

I've been asked by a student if [Perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) or [Marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) algorithm could be a good topic for a mathematical project (to study and present some mathematical results). I've looked into the two, and mathematically they look rather shallow, the ideas are on the surface, and no "deep" mathematical results are needed.

What are the most mathematically intensive methods used in the [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery)?